# Install Python 2.5 Setup on HMI Windows CE 5.0

Tags: python

I want to install Python 2.5 setup on HMI Windows CE 5.0 with ARM processor. Please tell me step by step procedure to install it properly.

Comment: Hey @Martin, Can you help me to install it properly??

Comment: The last time I attempted something like that I ended up compiling the whole of Python into my own CE project file. I am sure there are better solutions now.

Comment: Hey @Martin, Can you tell me how to run .py file on windows ce 5.0?